# Save & restoring WebView in an embedded PhoneGap app

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-webview

I have an Android app, which uses an embedded `PhoneGap WebView`. I've successfully implemented `CordovaInterface` on my activity and the app starts and functions how it should.

When I pause the app (switching to an other app or tabbing Home), I save the `WebView`'s state with the `saveState` method, which should be restored when the app starts again (this approach works in an app without `PhoneGap`).

However, when the app starts again, I try to to restore the state (with the `restoreState` method) without loading an url first (since I want to use the last state). This causes an error because PhoneGap expects an url to be loaded (at least that's what I gather from the exception).

**My question is: How can I correctly save and restore the WebView's state in an embedded PhoneGap WebView?**

**My `onCreate` method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        savedInstanceState = restoreFromPreferences();
    }
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.loadUrlIntoView(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
    }
}
```

**My `onPause` method (similar logic in `onSaveInstanceState`):**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Bundle out = new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(out);

    saveToPreferences(out);
}
```

**Error when closing/pausing app (solved - see update 1):**

I get an error, when I close the app. This is probably related, but I don't see how:

```
01-09 11:44:50.181: E/ActivityThread(2068): Activity my.package.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager$1@a6bc4020 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-09 11:44:50.181: E/ActivityThread(2068): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity my.package.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager$1@a6bc4020 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
...
```

**Error when starting app again (solved - see update 1):**

This causes an error, because the WebView tries to load an url which is null:

```
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:994)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlNow(CordovaWebView.java:499)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:384)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.onPageFinished(CordovaWebViewClient.java:298)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:327)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 11:38:22.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Both errors are resolved but replaced by a new one.

The first error was because `webView.handleDestroy()` in `onDestroy()` was not called.

The second error was due to field `baseUrl` in `CordovaWebView` which is not set. Currently I'm trying to resolve that by saving the last visited url into `SharedPreferences` when `onPause() / onSaveInstanceState()` occur:

```
        String url = webView.peekAtUrlStack();
        out.putString("url", url);
        webView.handlePause(true);
```

In `onResume()`, I load the url in `SharedPreferences`:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);           
        webView.loadUrlIntoView(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
    }
```

Now I get another (nasty) error. Strange thing is that the app immediately crashes (without notification). After a few tries it starts anyway. Here is the error:

```
01-09 15:11:19.869: A/libc(3392): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 3404 (WebViewCoreThre)
01-09 15:11:19.925: I/ActivityManager(281): Displayed my.package/.MainActivity: +197ms
01-09 15:11:19.973: I/DEBUG(86): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-09 15:11:19.973: I/DEBUG(86): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:4.1.1/JRO03L/eng.dan.20121106.232935:userdebug/test-keys'
01-09 15:11:19.973: I/DEBUG(86): pid: 3392, tid: 3404, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> my.package <<<
01-09 15:11:19.973: I/DEBUG(86): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
01-09 15:11:20.249: I/DEBUG(86):     eax 00000000  ebx b6b61c98  ecx 00000000  edx 00000001
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Restoring the WebView state occurred twice, which caused problems. So removed it from `onResume`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problems with restoring an embedded `CordovaWebView` were because the interactions with the `CordovaWebView` in `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` did not occur correctly. When starting to fix, restoreState() occurred twice which caused further problems.

**onCreate:**

Next to restoring the state, e need to setup the CordovaWebView base url by using method `loadUrlIntoView()`:

```
webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
webView.loadUrlIntoView(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
```

**onDestroy:**

We need to execute `handleDestroy()` to cleanup all PhoneGap related stuff, like the PluginManager, broadcast receivers, ...:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    webView.handleDestroy();
}
```

**onPause:**

In `onPause()`, we store the `CordovaWebView`'s state. We lookup the last registered url and we store it in `SharedPreferences`. Also, `handlePause()` needs to be called.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    String url = webView.peekAtUrlStack();
    webView.handlePause(true);

    Bundle out = new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(out);
    out.putString("url", url);

    saveToPreferences(out);
}
```

**onResume:**

In `onResume()` we need to call `CordovaWebView`'s `handleResume()`:

```
webView.handleResume(true, false);
```

**Conclusion:**

**Embedding a `CordovaWebView` and saving and restoring its state is possible, but because you have to know a lot of internals from `DroidGap` & `CordovaWebView`, it is NOT advisable to do so.**

I hope my answer will help somebody.

Comment: Is this possible to use [`onPause`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause) & [`onResume`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume) methods from Phone gap.

Comment: the onCreate and on Destroy code worked for me! thanks. the peekAtUrlStack method doesn't appear to be in my cordova library... i have v2.9.1

Comment: There is no method peekAtUrlStack in WebView and CordovaWebView class?