# Restoring Application State on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I've develop an Android app with phonegap, my app need to swicthing on the toggle button, then user can close the app and running it in background service. My problem is when I close the app and back to the app again, its back to the initial state with toggle button off. 
So, My question is how can we saving/restroring app state on android and phonegap?

I've read this [Save & restoring WebView in an embedded PhoneGap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233784/save-restoring-webview-in-an-embedded-phonegap-app) , but I still don't understand about **restoreFromPreferences()** and **saveToPreferences(out)** Can anyone help?

*Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @geet said, localStorage is what you need to store datas and retrieve them later.
According to Phonegap website, localstorage provides access to a W3C Storage interface. You can read about it here : http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute.

To save a toggle button position this is what I do :

```
<script>

function onDeviceReady() {

// Set togglebutton to false default
var togglebutton = window.localStorage.getItem("togglebutton");
if (togglebutton==null) window.localStorage.setItem("togglebutton", 'false');

// Set default state
if (window.localStorage.getItem("togglebutton")=='true') {
    $('#onoffswitch').attr("checked", "checked");
}

// Switch onoffswitch event
$('#onoffswitch').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("togglebutton", 'true');
    } else {
        window.localStorage.setItem("togglebutton", 'false');
    }
});

}

</script>
```

Make sure in your HTML that your toggle element (form me a checkbox) isn't checked by default :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="onoffswitch">
```

About Pause and Resume, you can perform actions when these events are called. To do this :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I see, so if I have many things to handle, I have to store it to storage one by one?

Comment: If you have only some values to store, localStorage is your friend. Otherwise, take a look to SQlite Phonegap databases http://docs.phonegap.com/fr/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 1):

U can store any data in localstorage in your JS.

e.g

To save value of `var username`.

```
localStorage.setItem("username",edited_name);
```

To retrive

```
var getUser=localStorage.getItem("username");
```

hope it will help to u!!

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? is it use Pause and Resume event on Phonegap?

Comment: Well you should be aware that it will cast all values to a String and then store as a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 
    var pageNow = document.getElementsByTagName(body);
    var currentPage = JSON.stringify(pageNow);
    localStorage.setItem("uiState", currentPage);

}

function onPause() {
//retrieve info here

var pageShow = document.getElementsByTagName(body);

let techStack = localStorage.getItem("uiState");
// JSON.parse(techStack); //unnecessary because the parser will detect HTML
pageShow.innerHTML(techStack);

}
}
```

you can get the current state of the UI in any element, just use a different selector.

will update this answer to incorporate SQL later